# variable referenced before definition when making a Noughts and Crosses/Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

So, I have been making a Xs and Os game, as a side project in Python 3.4, and I have encountered an issue. Whilst, it works, it does not save the board, since I have to define the slots in the `def game():`

If I define the slots outside of the `def game():`, even if I globalize them, it comes up with the error, `slot 1` (etc.) `referenced before definition` or whatever.
This is my code so far, and since I want a loop of turns, I have to put the game in a `def game():`

```
from time import sleep


gameboard = """
[1]
   [2]
      [3]
[4]
   [5]
      [6]
[7]
   [8]
      [9]
"""
print ("Welcome to Noughts and Crosses")
print ("The gameboard looks like this")
print (gameboard)


turn = (0)

def globalvar():
    global slot1
    global slot2
    global slot3
    global slot4
    global slot5
    global slot6
    global slot7
    global slot8
    global slot9
    global slotkeeper
    global slotkeeper1

globalvar()


global slotkeeper1
slotkeeper = (1)

def game():
    print ("Turn" ,turn + 1)
    xturn = input("X, please type a number where you want to place your marker")
    if xturn == ("1"):
        slot1 = """
[X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("2"):
        slot2 = """
    [X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("3"):
        slot3 = """
        [X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("4"):
        slot4 = """
[X]
"""
    elif xturn == ("5"):
        slot5 = """
    [X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("6"):
        slot6 = """
        [X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("7"):
        slot7 = """
[X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("8"):
        slot8 = """
    [X]
    """
    elif xturn == ("9"):
        slot9 = """
        [X]
    """
    oturn = input("O, please type a number where you want to place your marker")
    if oturn == ("1"):
        slot1 = """
[O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("2"):
        slot2 = """
    [O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("3"):
        slot3 = """
        [O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("4"):
        slot4 = """
[O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("5"):
        slot5 = """
    [O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("6"):
        slot6 = """
        [O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("7"):
        slot7 = """
[O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("8"):
        slot8 = """
    [O]
    """
    elif oturn == ("9"):
        slot9 = """
        [O]
    """

    while slotkeeper == (1):
        slot1 = """
[1]
"""
        slot2 = """
    [2]
"""
        slot3 = """
         [3]
"""
        slot4 = """
[4]
"""
        slot5 = """
    [5]
"""
        slot6 = """
         [6]
"""
        slot7 = """
[7]
"""
        slot8 = """
    [8]
"""
        slot9 = """
         [9]
"""
        slotkeeper = (0)

    sleep (0.6)    
    print (slot1, slot2, slot3)
    print (slot4, slot5, slot6)
    print (slot7, slot8, slot9)



def game2():
    sleep (0.6)
    slotkeeper = (0)
    game()

def gamefinal():
    game()
    game2()


gamefinal()
```

If you run it, you'll see what my problem is, since I need to make a `while` loop, inside the main defining of `game()` that is `while cond1 == (1)`
so basically, the slots remain that way whilst a condition is true, otherwise it will not save the board between turns, and I can't define the `cond1` outside of the main `def game():` or, even the slots without the error referenced before defining, even if I globalize them.

If I put the main defining of the slots outside of the `def game():`

```
       slot1 = """
[1]
"""
        slot2 = """
    [2]
"""
        slot3 = """
         [3]
"""
        slot4 = """
[4]
"""
        slot5 = """
    [5]
"""
        slot6 = """
         [6]
"""
        slot7 = """
[7]
"""
        slot8 = """
    [8]
"""
        slot9 = """
         [9]
"""
```

when it prints the slots, to show the current state of the gameboard, it goes to the error variable referenced before defining, like I said even if I globalize them, even without globalizing them in the `def globalvar():`, just normally, I still get this problem! If I define the slots at the start of the `def game():` It doesn't save the board (because it redefines the slots as those, obviously) and if I put the while loop on it at the start, it just stops, and stays as it is, after `print (gameboard)`, it does nothing, and apparently the program is still running, since it is, because the while loop needs to be true, or have an `else` statement after it, which doesn't work, and just breaks it!

EDIT: I tried using quotes around the `slotkeeper = ("1")`, inside the brackets, and changing `while slotkeeper == (1):` to `while slotkeeper == ("1")`, still no change. D:
EDITING THE EDIT: It does make a difference, but instead of getting an error message, it just gets stuck, even though I have globalized the variable, `slotkeeper` and set it to `("1")`, and in the `def game2():` I set it to `("0")`afterwards!

Comment: The `globalvar` function doesn't do what you probably think. It's useless, you might as well remove it.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  tried using it without the `globalvar()` but it still doesn't make a difference, I did say that at the end! (No offence), I tried to globalize it without and it doesn't make a difference, so I tried defining it with `globalvar`, and can't be bothered to remove it! :P

Comment: Ick this is a scary way to try and organize this. I'd look up some other tic-tac-toe implementations in Python and mimic that!

Comment: @AdamSmith I did... and they all print the board vertically, so I thought I would solve this, by making my own.. I'm stuck :(

Comment: @ClownBrains strongly consider wrapping your "slots" as a 2d list named `boards`. Consult [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/19503d04810e038a3d0c) I threw together quickly and didn't test! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're badly misunderstanding how Python's [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement works. You don't use it to declare a global variable. There's no need to declare anything, any assignment made at the top level of your module creates a global variable.

Rather, you use it in a function where you want to be able to modify a variable defined outside the function. So, move the `global` statements you currently have in your `globalvar` function (where they don't do anything useful) into your `game` function. This will let your code in `game` modify the global variables (and avoid the exceptions you're getting).

Note that using global variables is usually a symptom of poor design. This is especially true when you have a whole lot of them, as you do  in your program now. As a start towards a better design, I'd strongly suggest using a list or other data structure to hold your board data, rather than a bunch of separate variables.

Comment: THANK YOU! However, how come It could access the `turn` variable, but not the others from outside the `game` function?

Comment: You can always *access* global variables. It's only if you also want to assign to them from within a function that you need a `global` statement. You can read more about variables and their scopes in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

We use `global` keyword to access a global variable, not to declare it. Python is a dynamic language, declaration of variables don't make much sense anyway.

Secondly, why do you need so many global variables anyway. I'm sure you could figure out some other elegant way.

Thirdly, please don't use so many if/elif statements, use a dict instead, that would be much more pythonic -

```
slot_options = {
     "1": """
     [X]
     """,
     "2": """
         [X]
     """
     ...
}

slots = {}
slots[xturn] = slot_options[xturn]
```

something on these lines.

Fourthly, what's with all this "Drawings" representing 'X' position.

I recommend, checking out code of some current implementations and then craft your own. It might give you some pointers. You can check this one out - [Sample tic tac toe gist](https://gist.github.com/SudhagarS/3942029)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! However, after running it I get a buttload of errors saying that it was defined before becoming global .... Wait.. nope.. still getting stuck :(

Comment: Umm (Commenting on your edit) They need to be seperate, so they can be interacted with properly, when making the X and O press the numbers to choose their slot.